# How to make a permission for checking the Model only can be update by the belonged users?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The below is my code about model Domain's Update:

```
serializer.py:

class DomainUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Domain
        fields = "__all__"

models.py:
class Domain(models.Model):
    domain_name = models.CharField(max_length=512, help_text='domain. eg.example.com')
    cname = models.ForeignKey(
        unique=True,
        to=CNAMEModel,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name="domains",
        help_text="CNAME")
    ssl_cert = models.TextField(max_length=40960, help_text="SSL cert + ca-bundle")
    ssl_key = models.TextField(max_length=40960, help_text="SSL key")

    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain_name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.domain_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "domain"
        verbose_name_plural = "domain"
        ordering = ['ctime']

class CNAMEModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, help_text=". eg:gat.demo.com")
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=5120, null=True, blank=True, help_text="desc")

    desc_en = models.CharField(max_length=5120, null=True, blank=True")

    user = models.OneToOneField(unique=True, to=AuthUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, help_text="belong user")

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  

    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "CNAME"
        verbose_name_plural = "CNAME"
        ordering = ['ctime']

views.py:
class DomainUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DomainUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser]
    queryset = Domain.objects.all()
```

You see Domain belong to CNAME, CNAME belong to a user.

I have a question, how can I make a permission for checking the Domain only can be update by the belonged users or AdminUser(`IsAdminUser` have solved)?

Or use other way rather than permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a additional custom permission:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow creator of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the creator of the movie
        return obj.cname.user == request.user
```

And in the views **IsOwnerOrReadOnly** can be included:

```
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly

class DomainUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DomainUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Domain.objects.all()
```